# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.twilio.video.VideoTextureView cannot be cast to android.widget.VideoView

Tags: java, android, twilio

Does anyone have any information on how to get a broadcast link from the Twilio API?

I want to stream video with `VideoTextureView`. I tried to do it with the code below, but I couldn't find a broadcast link with the Twilio API.

I'm receiving the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
> com.twilio.video.VideoTextureView cannot be cast to
> android.widget.VideoView

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageButton button, button1, button2;
    private GridLayout gridLayout;
    private ImageView circle, dislike, like;
    private VideoView videoView;
    private String videoPath;
    private VideoTextureView videoTextureView;
    private Uri uri;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.circle);
        button1 = findViewById(R.id.dislike);
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.like);
       
        circle = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        dislike = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        like = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

        circle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        dislike.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        like.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        videoView = findViewById(R.id.video_view_top_right);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.video);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Circle", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Dislike", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Like", 
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Layout File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.twilio.video.VideoTextureView
        android:id="@+id/video_view_top_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:id="@+id/gift"
        android:layout_width="106dp"
        android:layout_height="106dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="492dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="168dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="61dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="244dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/launch1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="244dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/launch2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="428dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/launch3" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/circle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="37dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/launch1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/dislike"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.574"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/dislike"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@mipmap/launch2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.499"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"></ImageButton>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/like"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/launch3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.447"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dislike"></ImageButton>
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The error received:

```
2020-08-10 22:28:03.331 13296-13296/com.bariskarapelit.stajprojesi_1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.bariskarapelit.stajprojesi_1, PID: 13296
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bariskarapelit.stajprojesi_1/com.bariskarapelit.stajprojesi_1.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.twilio.video.VideoTextureView cannot be cast to android.widget.VideoView
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3126)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3269)
            at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1960)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7094)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.twilio.video.VideoTextureView cannot be cast to android.widget.VideoView
            at com.bariskarapelit.stajprojesi_1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7340)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7331)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1275)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3269) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1960) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7094) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Comment: Hi Baris. Welcome to posting on Stack Overflow. You have included your code and the error that you are receiving which is good, but you should start off by asking a clear question and make your post a little bit more social. Some tips for you here: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), Kind Regards.

Comment: I wanted to stream video with VideoTextureView.
                                                                                                                                    
I tried to do it with this code but I couldn't find a broadcast link with the twilio api.
Do you have any information? Get a broadcast link from the Twilio api

Comment: Can you post your XML file please. But it seems the XML file contains a VideoTextureView, but in the Java code it is being assigned to a reference of type VideoView which is an incorrect type. The hierarchy is shown in the docs here [VideoTextureView docs](https://twilio.github.io/twilio-video-android/docs/latest/com/twilio/video/VideoTextureView.html)

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/DFH-r8-z1K_67Q   I threw the xml file as a link

Comment: Okay I have added your XML file and up-voted the question. Let's see if someone answers. But in future, it is best to submit everything immediately because less people will see the question on the second day.

Comment: Ok. I didn't know that the second day less people saw it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stream video in android VideoView and use screencast API of Twilio to broadcast your video. Twilio's VideoTextureView is for showing the camera view or screen.
Follow the link below,

https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/android-screen-capture-v5